# I get an IOException in Butterknife viewbinder code I can't edit

Tags: java, android, ioexception, butterknife

I am working in android studio, using the butterknife.jar. But right know it is throwing an IOException in uneditable code. I throw the exception in the code that calls the method like this:

```
@OnClick(R.id.testButton)
public void Test() throws IOException {
     dispatchMakeJson("Test" + System.currentTimeMillis(),Link, Title, Description);
}
```

But in the viewbinder it says it wants to throw the exception again.

Does anybody know what I have to do here?

Comment: Try putting the content of the function dispatchMakeJson inside a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/

Without seeing more of your code I can't really help but this tutorial is quite comprehensive for butterknife so have a look through that to see if there are any irregularities in your code.